# Escaping double quotes in php echo

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello i am making a site on wordpress where some of the featured images have to be thumbnails of youtube video for that i am using the module Video Thumbnails however i cant seem to get it to work correctly. Using the following code

```
<?php 
    if( ( $video_thumbnail = get_video_thumbnail() ) != null ) { 
        echo "<a href=\"<?php echo get_permalink( $id ); ?>\"><img src='" . $video_thumbnail . "' /></a>"; 
    }
?>
```

i get the image of the youtube video if there is one however the link to the post is broken it shows like this `<a href="<?php echo get_permalink( 15544 ); ?>"><img src="http://www.test.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/15544.jpg"></a>`
\">"; } ?> insdead of the of the link of the actual post which is `http://www.test.com/?p=15544` i realize that the problem is probably in the escaping however i tried multiple escaping metods like \" or using ' for the echo and " for the actual string hoever i can seem to get it to work i know that my php sucks so i might not be escaping it right i would be gratefull for any advice.

Comment: You have the answer right in your code...

Comment: The problem is that you're using `<?php` tags when you're already inside PHP context. Try this instead: http://pastie.org/8973134

Comment: @Ivan Veselinov Nedelchev you don't need inner `echo` s. See my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this;

```
<?php 
    if( ( $video_thumbnail = get_video_thumbnail() ) != null ) { 
        echo "<a href=\"" . get_permalink( $id ) . "\"><img src='" . $video_thumbnail . "' /></a>"; 
    } 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make your code more readable and manageable with for example `printf()`:

```
if( ( $video_thumbnail = get_video_thumbnail() ) != null )
{ 
    printf( '<a href="%s"><img src="%s"/></a>', 
            get_permalink( $id ), 
            $video_thumbnail 
    ); 
}
```

and it's a good rule to *escape* the input values.

Check for example out the useful `esc_*` WordPress functions in the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation).

Comment: I see, but your code looks a bit more complex ^^ i would have to learn php a bit more to make beautiful code :) thanks for the tip thou.

Comment: Yes, it might be strange at first, but then you will probably soon start to love it ;-) It's used for example in the default WordPress themes.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like below

```
<?php 
    if( ( $video_thumbnail = get_video_thumbnail() ) != null ) { 
        echo "<a href=\"".get_permalink( $id )."\"><img src='" . $video_thumbnail . "' /></a>"; 
    } 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
<?php 
    if( ( $video_thumbnail = get_video_thumbnail() ) != null ) { 
        echo '<a href="'. echo get_permalink( $id ); .'"><img src='" . $video_thumbnail . "' /></a>"; 
    } 
?>
```